# Why is CGNS not used in CSM?

Tags: simulation, cfd, standards

The [CGNS](https://cgns.github.io/) format appears to be only applied in CFD (computational fluid dynamics). Why is it not applied in CSM (computational solid mechanics)? Is there any technical reason?

The hierarchical structure seems very reasonable and resembles that of the novel [VMAP](https://www.vmap.eu.com/) standard being developed within the CSM community.

Comment: The obvious reason is because it doesn't define any capabilities to store CSM related data. Of course it could be extended to include a lot of features that were of no use for CFD. As frame challenge to the question, why are the CFD community inventing their own standard, rather than using an existing one like ISO 10303 (aka STEP)?

Comment: @alephzero I have limited knowledge of the matter, but these are my thoughts: 1) you can store meshes and result data (e.g. temperature fields) within CGNS, which overlaps with CSM. 2) I don't know about ISO 10303, but afaik STEP is not a mesh format but a CAD-geometry format. How is this related to the question, am I missing something?